# boostrap modal not updating with vue js v2 two way binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, vue.js

I'm new to vue js and trying to use it with a bootstrap modal to view more data. My scenario is a table with multiple records and a button to see in depth details for the clicked record in a bootstrap modal. After clicking the first button it caches and doesn't update it while selecting another button for different details.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

(It's a combination of Laravel, jQuery and VueJS)

HTML Table:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>E-mail address</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Sent at</th>
        <th>Expires in</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="v-align-middle">
            john@doe.example
        </td>
        <td class="v-align-middle">
            <span class="label label-default">
                pending
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class="v-align-middle">
            2017-06-05 17:59:15
        </td>
        <td class="v-align-middle">
            29 days
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#inviteDetailsModal" data-email="john@doe.example">
                    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="v-align-middle">
            jane@doe.example
        </td>
        <td class="v-align-middle">
            <span class="label label-default">
                pending
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class="v-align-middle">
            2017-06-05 13:27:25
        </td>
        <td class="v-align-middle">
            29 days
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#inviteDetailsModal" data-email="jane@doe.example">
                    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('[data-target="#inviteDetailsModal"]').on('click', function () {
    let email = $(this).data('email'),
        baseUrl = $('html').data('base');

    Vue.component('invite-details', {
        data: function () {
            return {
                email: null,
                token: null,
                logs: [],
                expires: null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            update: function (data) {
                this.email = data['email'];
                this.token = data['token'];
                this.logs = data['logs'];
                this.expires = data['expires'];
            },
            fetchData: function () {
                this.$http.get(baseUrl + '/system/invites/' + email + '/details')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.update(response.body);
                    }, response => {
                        console.log('whoops something went wrong');
                    });
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.$el.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', this.fetchData());
        },
        beforeDestroy: function () {
            this.$el.removeEventListener('shown.bs.modal', this.fetchData());
        }
    });

    new Vue({
        el: '#inviteDetailsModal'
    });
});
```

The bootstrap modal:

```
<div class="modal fade slide-up" id="inviteDetailsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content-wrapper">
        <invite-details inline-template>
            <div class="modal-content" id="details">
                <div class="modal-header clearfix text-left">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                        <i class="pg-close fs-14"></i>
                    </button>
                    <h5>
                        Invite details for <span class="semi-bold">@{{ email }}</span>
                    </h5>
                    <p class="p-b-10">
                        <span data-tooltip="true" data-placement="bottom" title="token">
                            <em>@{{ token }}</em>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Sent at</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr v-for="log in logs">
                            <td>@{{ log.number }}</td>
                            <td>@{{ log.sentAt }}</td>
                            <td>@{{ log.status }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer text-center">
                    <span class="hint-text">
                        <em>expires in <strong>@{{ expires }}</strong> days</em>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </invite-details>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're using one modal component and trying to change its content based on the specific button in the table clicked? In that case, the `mounted` hook is only going to fire once when the component is initially mounted.

Comment: That's correct, so what should I do to update the modal content based on the specific button that's clicked in the table? Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I dug in deep to get this working and went the extra mile because you mentioned your were new at VueJS. I recognised my old self in your code where you go into VueJS with a JQuery mindset ;-)

First few quick notes before dropping the full code:

- Use the table DB row's integer ID to reference the user everywhere.
  This way when the email is updated, you still know who it is in the
  frontend. By examining the code I saw that the email can change
  (because it's an updateable `data` property, but it's also used in
  your `GET` request: `baseUrl + '/system/invites/' + email +
  '/details'`
- Subsequently, you can use this ID to easily generate unique instances
  of your modal :-) This is the way you want to be working with VueJS!
- Since you're using the same data in multiple places, have a look at
  Vuex for a store. It may look daunting at first but it's great once
  you get to grips with it. In your case, the same dataset would be
  used for the original table *and* the modals. If one updates,
  everything updates!
- With Vuex you can trigger updates from anywhere. Right now the data
  gets updated every time the eye button is clicked. However, this is
  pretty hacky as I've made the button part of the modal's template,
  and every time it gets clicked it calls `fetchData()` (check the
  console). What you want to do ideally is use Vuex and generate
  everything from the single point of truth dataset. Currently, if the
  modal's data is updated, the original table is not.
- With VueJS it's just as easy to create your own modal. The upside of
  this is less overhead in your code, as you can use `v-if`, so it
  won't be loaded into the DOM unless actually required. And judging
  from your current code, the details button would be clicked
  occasionally.
- Install VueJS debugger if you haven't already:
  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd,
  it will help you 'see' under the hood.

Alright so now for the code! First, add this line to your `app.js` file:

```
import JaimyTable from './components/stackoverflow/JaimyTable.vue'
```

Right above the `var app = new Vue({` line. And add it to your components, so you end up with something like this:

```
import JaimyTable from './components/stackoverflow/JaimyTable.vue'

var app = new Vue({

    components: {
        JaimyTable,
    },

});
```

Here's the JaimyTable.vue file:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>E-mail address</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Sent at</th>
                <th>Expires in</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="v-align-middle">
                    john@doe.example
                </td>
                <td class="v-align-middle">
            <span class="label label-default">
                pending
            </span>
                </td>
                <td class="v-align-middle">
                    2017-06-05 17:59:15
                </td>
                <td class="v-align-middle">
                    29 days
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group pull-right">

                        <jaimy-modal id="1"></jaimy-modal>

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="v-align-middle">
                    jane@doe.example
                </td>
                <td class="v-align-middle">
                <span class="label label-default">
                    pending
                </span>
                </td>
                <td class="v-align-middle">
                    2017-06-05 13:27:25
                </td>
                <td class="v-align-middle">
                    29 days
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group pull-right">

                        <jaimy-modal id="2"></jaimy-modal>

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import JaimyModal from './JaimyModal.vue'

    export default {

        components: { JaimyModal },

        props: [],

        mixins: [],

        data: function () {
            return {
                //
            }
        },

        computed: {
            computed_variable() {
                return '';
            }
        },

        created() {
            //
        },

        mounted() {
            //
        },

        methods: {
            //
        },

        watch: {
            //
        }
    }
</script>
```

And please note the `<jaimy-modal id="1"></jaimy-modal>` lines. You probably want to use `v-for` to generate the all the `<tr>` rows automatically :) Make sure the `id=` corresponds to the ID in your database.

Now for the `JaimyModal.vue` where all the magic happens:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" :data-target="'#inviteDetailsModal' + id" @click="fetchData()">
            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
        </a>

        <div class="modal fade slide-up" :id="'inviteDetailsModal' + id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content-wrapper">


                    <div class="modal-content" id="details">
                        <div class="modal-header clearfix text-left">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                <i class="pg-close fs-14"></i>
                            </button>
                            <h5>
                                Invite details for <span class="semi-bold">{{ email }}</span>
                            </h5>
                            <p class="p-b-10">
                        <span data-tooltip="true" data-placement="bottom" title="token">
                            <em>{{ token }}</em>
                        </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Sent at</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr v-for="log in logs">
                                    <td>{{ log.number }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ log.sentAt }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ log.status }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer text-center">
                            <span class="hint-text">
                                <em>expires in <strong>{{ expires }}</strong> days</em>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        props: ['id'],

        data: function () {
            return {
                email: null,
                token: null,
                logs: [],
                expires: null,
                baseUrl: 'https://yourbaseurl.com',
            }
        },

        mounted: function () {
            //
        },

        methods: {
            update: function (data) {
                this.email = data['email'];
                this.token = data['token'];
                this.logs = data['logs'];
                this.expires = data['expires'];
            },
            fetchData: function () {
                console.log('data fetched');

                // Commented out for local purposes
//                this.$http.get(this.baseUrl + '/system/invites/' + this.email + '/details')
//                        .then(response => {
//                            this.update(response.body);
//                        }, response => {
//                            console.log('whoops something went wrong');
//                        });

                // Dummy data
                this.update({
                    email: 'test@test ' + this.id + '.com',
                    token: 'token123123asdsasdasdasd',
                    logs: [
                        {
                            number: 1,
                            sentAt: '2017-01-01',
                            status: 'Ok',
                        },
                        {
                            number: 2,
                            sentAt: '2017-02-01',
                            status: 'Failed',
                        },
                    ],
                    expires: '2017-10-01'
                });
            }
        },

    }
</script>
```

Important to note here is the `:data-target="'#inviteDetailsModal' + id"` part in the button, where the number corresponds to the id of the prop. By using the `:` you're making it an expression, and it resolves to a unique reference.

As you can see the setup is completely different than you had before. Where the modal is a nested component of your table row. Once you start thinking of Components as recurring parts of look and functionality, but with unique data within it, things will *click* fast. Think of it as Model in Laravel.

After a long time of being told that you need to separate design (CSS), mark-up (HTML) and functionality (JS), it's weird to have it all sitting there in 1 file. But embrace it, and you'll fall in love with VueJS :D

And give Vuex a look! The second you get multiple components that use and manipulate the same dataset, it's a god-send!

Ow and finally: the second you start thinking of using things like fn.trigger and whatnot, you're approaching VueJS wrong. Keep that in mind :) It has all the tools necessary for you to work with the page, and then some!

Happy coding!

Comment: Ahh thanks for the full in depth explanation @stan-smulders, it's always a little hard learning a new language while your mind has been trainend for "old" ways like jQuery... i really like the way vuejs works but need more practice to get my head around it... so really thanks for this, it helped me a lot! Works like a charm!

Comment: You're more than welcome Jaimy! Its a great framework once things click so keep at it and you'll have a great working knowledge of it in no-time :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using one modal component and are attempting to change its content based on the specific button in the table clicked, the `mounted` hook is only going to fire once when the component is initially mounted.

What you want is for the content to update each time the modal is shown.

First of, it looks like your component only needs one `email` prop. Move the rest of the props to be in the `data` method for the component, since (I'm assuming) they aren't being passed into the component:

```
props: ['email'],
data: function() {
  return {
    token: null,
    logs: null,
    expires: null,
  }
}
```

Then, I would create a new method called `fetchData` to put the `$http.get` call in:

```
fetchData: function() {
  this.$http.get('http://localhost:2000/system/invites/' + this.email + '/details')
    .then(response => {
      this.update(response.body);
    }, response => {
      console.log('whoops something went wrong');
    });
}
```

In your modal component's `mounted` hook, add a listener to the bootstrap modal's `show` event using jQuery. And be sure to remove the listener in the component's `beforeDestroy` hook:

```
mounted() {
  $(this.$el).on('shown.bs.modal', this.fetchData);
}, 
beforeDestroy() {
  $(this.$el).off('shown.bs.modal', this.fetchData);
}
```

Now, every time the modal's `show` event fires, the `$http.get` request will fire based on the current value of the component's `email` property.

[Here's an example fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nckbryd1/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but still i've got the issue that the modal won't update it's contents... i've updated my first message with the full code that i have for now

Comment: @jaimyborgman apparently, jQuery is required for listening to bootstrap's events. I've updated my answer

Comment: mmm still not updating... it looks like the beforeDestroy hook isn't called if i set an console.log() in there...

Comment: It's probably not getting called because it looks like, from your code example, you are creating a new Vue instance each time you click a button to show a modal. That's a bad way to do it. Can you show the template with your table and modal?